# Copy command with LONG datatype - ora-00997 illegal use of long datatype

Tags: oracle

Here is my synax for my code. And I can't figure out a way of how to get around this... I have to pull from hundreds of tables with one column having a LONG datatype.

```
set long 64000
set copycommit 100
set arraysize 100
copy from UserName/PassWord@Server -  
insert into TargetTable using select * from SourceTable;
commit;
quit;
```

I get this error - ora-00997 illegal use of long datatype

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Been asked a boatload of times before. Have you reviewed https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=illegal+use+of+long any of those?

Comment: Yes I have gone over them. It looks like for a lot of people, advise was to try converting to CLOB datatype. Sadly I don't have access to modify all the source tables to convert the datatype.  On my target table, I have freedom to change the datatype to anything if it would work.

Comment: So if you can make your target table anything, why not have it contain a clob column and call to_lob() on the long when you're selecting it out of sourceTable ?